# Least Developed Countries and non-Least Developed Countries

Tags: economy, trade

According to the East African Community EU Economic Partnership agreement http://ec.europa.eu/trade/policy/countries-and-regions/regions/eac/
Rwanda, Tanzania, Uganda and Burundi are termed as Least Developed Countries and the trade terms with the EU is duty free quota free for trade in goods while Kenya is put in a different bracket of Non- LDCs and therefore the kind of trade should be reciprocal.

What is the difference between Kenya and its partner states (we are all members of one trading block and customs Union - the EAC http://www.eac.int) for it to be termed as non-LDC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“[Least developed country](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_developed_country)” is a category developed by the UN's development agencies. There is an official list of “least-developed countries” and the EU only uses/refers to this typology.

Basically, it means that those countries are especially poor even compared to Kenya and other developing countries. Even if the definition includes many indices to avoid an approach based purely on the GDP, you can see that Rwanda and Uganda have a [GDP per capita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_GDP_(nominal)_per_capita) that's roughly half that of Kenya (Burundi is even poorer and Tanzania is in-between, very close to the limit to be listed as a least-developed country).